# Using python regex to replace every instance of self.kwargs.get('arg') with self.arg

Tags: python, regex

Here is a string:

```
string='''assert self.kwargs.get('scan_type') in scan_types
        assert self.kwargs.get('quantity_type') in quantity_type_list
        assert self.kwargs.get('scheduled') in [True, False]
        assert self.kwargs.get('clear_scans') in [True, False]
        assert self.kwargs.get('run') in [True, False]'''
```

I would like to change all occurrences of:

```
self.kwargs.get('arg')
```

with:

```
self.arg
```

I've worked out that the regex pattern to match this type of phrase is:

```
pattern = self.kwargs.get\('(.*)'\)
```

How can I use this pattern to replace all instances of `self.kwargs.get('arg')` to `self.arg`?

I've tried using `re.sub` but I'm not sure how to use the output of the `pattern` (i.e. the contents of the capture group) within the replacement clause of `re.sub`.

Comment: Replace with `r'self.\1'`

Comment: this works as well `re.sub(r'self.kwargs.get', r'self.args', string)`